# Kann man sagen, dass ein Text bzw. eine Grafik unter irgendwelchem Namen "firmiert"?

Tags: word-usage

Ist es stilistisch und auch inhaltlich richtig zu sagen:

> Der Text, der unter dem Namen "..." firmiert, ...

Oder wie kann man sonst "einen Titel tragen" umschreiben? Ich suche eher nach einer nicht herkömmlichen Variante, wie z.B. dem Ausdruck "er hört auf den Namen XY" statt "er heißt XY"

Comment: @Robert 's Antwort nennt bereits gute Alternative. Mit einem Beispiel für solch einen Text oder eine Grafik wäre es aber noch einfacher, die Frage zu beantworten.

Comment: Es kommt hier sehr auf den Kontext an, in dem du diese Formulierung verwenden willst. Klar "kann" man sagen, dass ein Text unter dem Namen xzy firmiert, aber ob der Ausdruck gut gewählt ist, hängt vom Kontext ab. In der Regel klingt es, wie die Antworten unten ja auch sagen, "gestelzt" oder sonstwie ungeschickt, aber theoretisch sind schon Kontexte möglich, wo auch ein geschultes Sprachempfinden den Ausdruck für gut gewählt halten würde, vielleicht in bestimmten ironischen oder sarkastischen Umgebungen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Der Text, der unter dem Namen "..." firmiert

klingt für mich extrem gestelzt und falsch. [Firmieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/firmieren) bezieht sich auf Unternehmen und deren Namen, und ggf. rechtliche Bedeutungen dazu.

Wie wäre es mit

- als / unter "..." veröffentlicht
- als / unter "..." bekannt
- mit dem Titel "..."

Denk auch daran, dass bei "einen Titel tragen" meist ein akademischer Titel gemeint ist. Das kommt für Texte eh nicht in Frage.

Answer (score 2):

"Der Text erschien unter der Überschrift..."

Wenn man einmal miterlebt hat, wie in Redaktionen gerade Titel gnadenlos geändert oder an verschiedenste Umstände angepasst werden, verabschiedet sich sehr schnell von der Vorstellung, der Titel wäre ein essentieller Bestandteil eines Textes. Im Gegenteil ist er der am wenigsten verlässliche und unveränderliche Teil. Das Wort "firmieren" (d.h. formal ins Handelsregister eingetragen sein) vermittelt da genau den falschen Eindruck.